# fastboot flashall -w Halts

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, fastboot

I have a Samsung Nexus S.
I have erased `recovery` and `boot` pertitions using `fastboot erase <partition>`
and when I do `fastboot flashall -w` it stops on

`sending 'boot' (XXXX KB)...`

What might be wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I successfully managed to flashed my NS back to stock ROM.
Please refer to my own answer below.

Regards,

Comment: Have you tried only flashing the system image, or recovery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NOTE: attempting `fastboot flash` on ur device may cost you your data.
>   So be careful

I figured out that I had an outdated Android SDK. I downloaded the latest one, and did:

`fastboot flash boot`

`fastboot flash recovery`

`fastboot flash userdata`

and in a couple of minutes I had the stock ROM up and running.